# Modal event in boostrapVue with vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, vuex

I have a component that contains a modal component:

**UserComponent:**

I send an id:

```
    `<a href="#"  class="text-primary" data-toggle="modal" >
           <i @click.prevent="item(tag.id)"class="fa fa-fw fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
     </a>`
```

function you receive:

```
    `item: function(id){this.$store.dispatch('getViewProfile', id);},`
```

my vuex module:

```
        `export default {
            state: {
                    item:[],
             },
        mutations: {
         LOAD_PROFILE(state, data){
                    state.itemProfile = data;
                },
        }
        actions:{

     getViewProfile: function(context, id){
                let that = this;
                let url = '/user/'+id;
                axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    context.commit('LOAD_PROFILE', {
                        'user': response.data,
                    });
                }).catch(function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                });
    }`
```

I using the bootstrapVue library in my modal component:

```
    `<b-modal ref="view-profile-modal" hide-footer title="Using Component Methods">
        Hello World
    </b-modal>`
```

function:

```
    `computed:{
     user: function () {
                   if(typeof this.$store.state.users.itemProfile.user !== 'undefined') {
                       return this.$store.state.users.itemProfile.user;
                   }
               },
    }`
```

I receive the information well, what I cannot obtain is that the modal is executed, because it tells me that it cannot find show()

```
     `this.$refs['view-profile-modal'].show()`
```

but if I run the modal in the main component it works!
Some help for this rookie: 3
P/d: I am loading the components in the app.js of laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try assigning an ID to the b-modal and then using `this.$bvModal.show('view-profile-modal')` instead. Make sure you import it properly in your main.js or app.js file using:

`import { ModalPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'`

`Vue.use(ModalPlugin)`